# Attribute jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes is not allowed here

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jaxb, xjc

I've checked out one project and trying solving some problems in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1. In one of the maven project I've got following xjb file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="3.0" xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:simple />
        <xjc:serializable uid="-1" />
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
            parseMethod="jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
            printMethod="jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

But I've got an error here:
Attribute jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes is not allowed here

Does anybody knows how to solve it? Thanks very much.

Comment: The file is okay. If the Maven execution runs fine, the problem is IDEA. Maybe the new Jakarta-Schemas aren't supported already.

Comment: get it, and I don't need scratch the documents. Thank you,bro

Answer (score 1):

The binding file is valid if accepted by XJC.

The point here is that IntelliJ doesn't seem to have a complete XSD for the bindingschema reference :
[image: bindingschema_3_0.xsd]

You can check here for the latest documentation regarding XJC Customizations within XSD, but same applies to binding files : [jaxb-ri extensions xjc customizations](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/4.0.3/docs/release-documentation.html#jaxb-ri-extensions-xjc-customizations)

Comment: 3Q,bro,I start RTFM